# Instrumenting (logging) Scala expressions

Tags: scala, logging, expression, instrumentation

(**UPD** after @krivachy.akos )

How to debug expressions in Scala? You don't have an opportunity to set a breakpoint and see local variables in most cases because inside the expression there are no variables. And usually there are no statements to which you can set a breakpoint.

One old way of debugging is to have the code instrumented. This gives an indispensable information about the internal processing of expressions.

However, in a typical logging implementation there are no direct ways of intercepting expressions. In particular, a typical logger have methods with `Unit` return type:

```
def debug(msg: =>String) {...}
```

To use the logger one have to rewrite concise expression in a way to be able to call logger:

**Example 1**:

if you have some boolean-based rules with complex conditions and multiple evaluation paths:

```
val x = if(condition1(a,b)) 
          Some(production1(a,b))
        else if(condition2(c,d))
          Some(production2(a,b))
        else
          None
```

then it is hard to make sure it works as desired. ( It's not always possible to avoid complex rules altogether. And representation rules in OOP-style is not always good.)

Then a typical instrumentation would require introduction of some intermediate variables and blocks of code:

```
debug("a="+a)
debug("b="+b)
val x = if(condition1(a,b)) {
          debug("rule1 hit")
          val production = production1(a,b)
          debug("rule1 result: "+production)
          Some(production)
        } else { 
          debug("rule1 doesn't hit")
          debug("c="+c)
          debug("d="+d)
          if(condition2(c,d)){
            debug("rule2 hit")
            Some(production2(a,b))
          } else
            None
        }
```

**Example 2**:

```
def f(list:List[Int]) = 
    list.
        map(_*2).
        flatMap(t =>
            (0 until t).
            map(_+1)
        )
```

Instrumentation will lead to some intermediate variables:

```
def f(list:List[Int]) = {        
    val twiced = list.map(_*2)
    debug(s"twiced = $twiced")
    val result = twiced.flatMap(t => {
        val widened = (0 until t).map(_+1)            
        debug(s"widened = $widened")
        widened
    })
    debug(s"result = $result")
    result
}
```

Very ugly, I suppose. And this instrumentation takes more space than the code itself. The main reason, I think, is that the logger is incompatible with an expression evaluation style.

Is there a way to log expression values in a more concise way?

Answer (score 0):

I recently found a nice way of logging the value of an expression:

```
trait Logging {

    protected val loggerName = getClass.getName
    protected lazy val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerName)

    implicit class RichExpressionForLogging[T](expr: T){
        def infoE (msg: T ⇒ String):T = {if (logger.isInfoEnabled ) logger.info (msg(expr)); expr}
        def traceE(msg: T ⇒ String):T = {if (logger.isTraceEnabled) logger.trace(msg(expr)); expr}
        def debugE(msg: T ⇒ String):T = {if (logger.isDebugEnabled) logger.debug(msg(expr)); expr}      
        def infoL (msg: String):T = {if (logger.isInfoEnabled ) logger.info (msg+expr); expr}
        def traceL(msg: String):T = {if (logger.isTraceEnabled) logger.trace(msg+expr); expr}
        def debugL(msg: String):T = {if (logger.isDebugEnabled) logger.debug(msg+expr); expr}       
    }

}
```

Here how it is used:

**Example 1 (rules):**

```
val x = if(condition1(a.debugL("a="),b.debugL("b="))) 
      Some(production1(a,b).debugL("rule1="))
    else if(condition2(c,d))
      Some(production2(a,b).debugL("rule2="))
    else
      None
```

**Example 2:**

```
def f(list:List[Int]) = 
    list.
        map(_*2).
        debugE(s"res1="+_).
        flatMap(t => (0 until t).
            map(_+1).
            debugE(s"res2="+_)).
        debugE(s"res="+_)
```

It can also be used everywhere in expressions:

```
if((a<0).debugE(s"a=$a<0="+_))

for{
    a <- f(list).debugE("f(list)="+_)
    b <- a.debugL("a=")
} yield b.debugL("b=")
```

Of course you should mix-in Logging trait to your class.

This kind of instrumentation doesn't hide the logic of the code.

Comment: It allows to have expression values logged without boilerplate. And can be embedded directly in an expression.

Comment: Your solution is good, but definitely not nice. It seems like a solution to overcome bad coding practices. I would say if you chain so many methods together and need to hack in logging to actually debug your code then you **don't know what your code actually does**. Good and clear Scala code **has intermediate variables that are named aptly** to help other programmers (and you) to understand what the code does. Please watch [Martin Odersky's ScalaDays 2013 keynote](http://parleys.com/play/51c1994ae4b0d38b54f4621b/chapter22/about) from 42:00 and consider revising your practices.

Comment: Well, I should have put more real life expressions. The examples of expressions are a bit artificial. The point is to have some way to barge in the expression evaluation without having to rewrite it with intermediate vals.

Comment: @ArseniyZhizhelev Ok, I guess it makes a bit more sense now. BTW, what does the `E` and the `L` stand for at the end of the methods?

Comment: E - expression, L - label. I couldn't use simple `debug` because it is already reserved for `:Unit` variant. You may suggest other names for method names.